# ruby on rails redcarpet code block not respecting indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redcarpet

I am trying to use recarpet in a rails 5 application, everything works fine except for the fact that indentations are not respected in code blocks. I setup redcarpet in my ApplicationHelper file as Shawn below.

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def markdown(text)
        options = { 
          filter_html:     true,
          hard_wrap:       true,
          link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" },
      space_after_headers: true,
      lax_html_blocks:    true,
          fenced_code_blocks: true
        }
    
        extensions = {
          autolink:           true,
          superscript:        true
        }
    
        renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
        markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
    
        markdown.render(text).html_safe
    end
end
```

then in my view I called the markdown method as
`<%= markdown(@blog.body) %>`
So when I post an article using my form, for example

```
def function
  return you are real
end
```

It renders in the browser as

```
def function
return you are real
end
```

thereby not respecting the indentation. I don't know if I am missing out on an option.

Comment: The code block in `@blog.body` needs to either [have lines that start with 4 spaces](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#code-blocks) or it needs to be [fenced by 3 backticks](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks).

Comment: Ya that was exactly what I did but it rendered without spaces, but I solved the problem, I notice every block code should be at least two spaces away from other text or paragraphs for the indentation to be respected. fore example.

paragraph............... 2 extra spaces

block_code 2 extra spaces

paragraph..... 

I don't know why but it works.